# angularfire Circular dependency in DI

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I am using
"@angular/fire": "^7.0.0",
"firebase": "^9.0.0",
@angular : 12

imports in app module:

```
provideFirebaseApp(() => {
  const app = initializeApp(environment.firebase);
  return app;
}),
provideAuth(() => {
  const auth = getAuth();
  return auth;
}),
```

in constructor :
public auth:AngularFireAuth,

Error message:

````
core.js:6456 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(HdauthModule)[AngularFireAuth -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(HdauthModule)[AngularFireAuth -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!

core.js:6456 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for AngularFireAuth. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0200
Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for AngularFireAuth. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0200
    at throwCyclicDependencyError (core.js:216)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11412)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11236)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:25341)
    at Object.get (core.js:25055)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.js:3342)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.js:3454)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.js:14714)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.SignUpComponent_Factory [as factory] (sign-up.component.ts:18)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.js:3549)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1213)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1167)
    at zone.js:1279
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28661)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:582)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:491)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1600)```
````

Comment: I only use the angularfire auth